# Changed namespace not found unless prepended with global::

Tags: c#, namespaces

So I recently renamed my data access layer's namespace from Client.Project.DataAccess to Project.DataAcess

Next, I went and changed all the `using Client.Project.DataAccess;` instances to reflect the name change, only to discover that names in the namespace won't be resolved unless I do `using global::Project.DataAccess;`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have the old DLLs lying around? Is there other code using this namespace?

Comment: Nope, scrubbed everything clean. I've got namespaces in other assemblies like Client.Project.BusinessLogic and Client.Project.Web etc if that's relevant...

Comment: Might be causing a namespace conflict, though not if you don't have another `DataAccess` namespace.

Comment: It's not a namespace conflict, but it turns out there's a _class_ of the same name (Project) which gets in the way of resolving Project.DataAccess, thus requiring me to use global::

Comment: Then it _is_ a naming conflict.

Comment: @Veli: it's worth bearing in mind that there is no such thing as a 'namespace' in .NET. This is a language concept only. I.e. if you have a type with a C# name 'Foo' defined in a C# namespace 'Project.DataAcess' then _the name of your type_ is, in fact,  Project.DataAcess.Foo

Comment: @Oded: Hehe yeah, I meant the problem wasn't another DataAccess namespace. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like you have a `Project` class - this is causing the naming conflict you are seeing, requiring you to resolve the conflict using the `global::` alias.